# New Facebook IOS SDK? Can we use the old sdk with the new sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, sdk

I am currently adding new Facebook iOS sdk 3.1.1 to my iPhone application. I saw the sdk have significant changes. E.g. My old sdk create a Facebook object and call the requestGraphPath:AndDelegate from the FBRequest object. Now the new sdk have no header file "Facebook.h" and "FBRequest" have no requestGraphPath:AndDelegate but it has a same method name with a handler... and have extra function as well.

Does that mean I have to recoding all the Facebook stuff of my application to accommodate the new Facebook SDK

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would need to change your code. The latest facebook SDK has iOS 6 integration and lots of other features. Read about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/

Basically in the latest SDK, everything is managed via the FBSession.

This SDK is backwards compatible meaning, even if the users have not upgraded to iOS 6, this will work in iOS 5.